# sed command within GitHub Actions to deploy on GKE

Tags: sed, github-actions, devops, google-kubernetes-engine, cicd

Below is my workflow:

```yaml
- name: Build Docker image in prod
  run: docker build . --tag gcr.io/${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}/pythonapp:${GITHUB_SHA}
# Generates an execution plan for Terraform
- name: Push Docker image in prod
  run: docker push gcr.io/${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}/pythonapp:${GITHUB_SHA}

- name: Connect to GKE
  uses: google-github-actions/get-gke-credentials@v0
  with:
    cluster_name: ${{ secrets.CLUSTER }}
    location: ${{ secrets.CLUSTER_ZONE }}

- name: Lock image version in deployment.yaml
  run: sed -i 's/PROJECT_ID/${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}/g; s/COMMIT_TAG/${GITHUB_SHA}/g' applications/app/app.yaml

- name: Deploy to GKE
  run: kubectl apply -f applications/app/app.yaml
```

In this, build image and push image work and I can see the image updated with the hash value generated by GitHub in the container registry.

However, there is some problem with respect to `sed` command as it is not working as expected within the job (even though the job executes).

After the workflow executes I get an error when I check the pod that the image name is invalid.

Can we use `sed` command within an action like above? How can we debug this?

**Update**

when i run cat applications/app.app.yaml in the workflow I get the below

```
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: app
          image: gcr.io/***/pythonapp:$***GITHUB_SHA***
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
          imagePullPolicy: Always
```

seems it is correct

**Update**

when i run the below to get the container name for my deployment i get the output as

```
kubectl get deployment app -o=jsonpath='{$.spec.template.spec.containers[:1].image}'
gcr.io/my-project-id/pythonapp:${GITHUB_SHA}
```

seems like GITHUB_SHA gets replaced by sed as is as a literal string.

Comment: Debugging: print the file as part of the pipeline and check if the changes are what you expected? Also, consider using something like `yq` to manipulate YAML. It's pre-installed on GitHub-hosted runners.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I updated my question and I can see the contents as shown in the update. It looks like the file is fine.

Comment: Variables don't expand in single quotes. You have to use double quotes for your sed command.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I tried using s/COMMIT_TAG/${{ GITHUB_SHA }}/g'. But it did not work

Comment: Thanks I used ${{ github.sha }} and it worked.